# Why doesn't make_optional work for file streams?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, option-type, filestream

I'm trying out the C++17 optional-type, and thought a fitting place to use it would be a function that attempts to open a file and *maybe* returns the opened file. The function I wrote looks like this:

```
std::optional<std::fstream> openFile(std::string path)
{
    std::fstream file;
    file.open(path);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "couldn't open file" << path << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
    else
    {
        return std::make_optional(file); // results in compilation error
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile this with g++ with `-std=c++17` as one of the arguments I get a big wall of template compilation error messages, starting with:

```
In file included from read_file.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/optional: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::optional<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> std::make_optional(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = std::basic_fstream<char>&; typename std::decay<_Tp>::type = std::basic_fstream<char>]’:
read_file.cpp:16:39:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/optional:991:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::optional<std::basic_fstream<char> >::optional(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     { return optional<decay_t<_Tp>> { std::forward<_Tp>(__t) }; }
```

Why would it seem as if `fstream` can't be used with `std::optional`? Am I approaching this in the wrong way? If optional doesn't support stream-types, does that not limit where the type can be applied?

Comment: Which is line 16?

Comment: @ecatmur `return std::make_optional(file); // results in compilation error` is line 16.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code will try and copy the stream, when you pass it to `make_optional`. Streams can't be copied, therefore, you need to move it, i.e.,

```
return std::make_optional(std::move(file));
```

or simply

```
return file;
```

(Depending on the age of the compiler, the latter might not work.)

Comment: just `return file` ^^

Comment: Indeed, I'll add it to the answer, but it hides what's actually happening a bit.

Comment: i prefer the hiding and appreciate the "it just works". ymmv.

Comment: I think the long form serves as education, the short form as the form for actual code.

Comment: I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, and just returning the file results in a compilation error because it apparently doesn't implicitly convert the stream into an optional. Explicitly moving the stream into the make_optional _does_ work however! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_optional` calls the optional constructor with the form of

```
template < class U = value_type >
constexpr optional( U&& value );
```

and that constructor behaves as doing

```
T optional_data = std::forward<U>(value)
```

which is going to make a copy since you passed an lvalue.  Streams are not copyable, so you get an error.  You have to `move` the stream into the optional to get it to work correctly.